# PHP cURL post to a form that is being processed by jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, post, curl

Ok, so usually I would lookup the form's action attribute (ex: request.php) and would do a cURL post request to that page, but what if the form is being processed by jQuery? 
Example

```
<form method="post" action="profile/post/USERNAME" id="postForm"
    onsubmit="funct.post('USERNAME'); return false;" >
...
<input type="button" class="sendButton" id="sendBtn" value="Send"
    onclick="funct.post('USERNAME')" />
```

I have no idea how to work with this form, I've tried submitting to the /profile/post/USERNAME page, but that doesn't work. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: What data are you expecting to be returned form your request? What is not happening that you want to? Have you tried examining the funct.post function?

Comment: The site's jQuery is BIG, so not really, it's in some external file, and they have like 6 attached. Do you think that might be useful? I was thinkings that /profile/post/USERNAME should be enough for the URL, but ... For the data I'm expecting, I'm not really expecting anything, just my query to be posted, but it says "Invalid request"

Comment: I am still not aware of what response you are expecting that you are not getting. And yes, it would be a good idea to trundle through the external .js file anyways.

Comment: Definitely worth checking the ``funct.post()`` method, since that will tell you what processing it's doing. Of course it's possible that all this does is to perform the post via AJAX, and the problem you are experiencing has nothing to do with the form being processed by jQuery at all. Firebug should make investigation the ``funct.post()`` code fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was having problems because the form is using AJAX to post the form.
If looking through MASSIVE, unformatted amount of jQuery code (like in my case) is a problem and doesn't lead anywhere, then a good idea is to look at the headers that are being sent to the server.

I used [HTTP Live Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) addon for Firefox to see just that, and noticed that the actual query was `token=4324234324&note=My+Note&ajax=1`
Both token and note were present in the form, token as hidden and note as text input, but the ajax=1 is inserted somewhere when it's processed by jQuery.

Headers Don't Lie!